# JavaFX animated polygon artifacts

Tags: java, javafx, transition, polygon, artifacts

I'm working on a small game in JavaFX where I move polygons using a PathTransition.
I encountered an issue that I just could not find a fix for:
when moving the polygons they sometimes leave a trace of artifacts behind:
[artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GHa4.png)
This doesn't really happen regularly *(but only when moving left or right, never in both directions)* and they ususally disappear at some point.

A small example below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application{

private Scene testScene;
private FXMLLoader testLoader;
private Pane testPane;
private Polygon polygon;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    testLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));
    try {
        testPane = (Pane) testLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    testScene = new Scene(testPane, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(testScene);

    polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.setFill(Color.DARKSLATEBLUE);
    polygon.getPoints().setAll(new Double[]{ 50.0, 50.0, 70.0, 50.0, 70.0, 70.0, 50.0, 70.0 });

    TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition();     
    transition.setCycleCount(1);
    transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(4));
    transition.setNode(polygon);
    transition.setFromX(0);
    transition.setToX(0);
    transition.setFromY(0);
    transition.setToY(400);
    transition.play();

    testPane.getChildren().add(polygon);        

    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    launch(args);   
 }  

}
```

The test.fxml used is the vanilla fxml-file created with eclipse *(e(fx)clipse maybe?)* that looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
</AnchorPane>
```

**Note:** The problem doesn't occur every time in the provided example, more like half of the time so you might have to try multiple times to reproduce it...

Does anyone have an idea what could cause a polygon to behave like that?

Comment: It shouldn't do that, please provide a [mcve] (short, complete program which demonstrates the issue and somebody could just copy and paste to replicate it on their PC).

Comment: I edited the post.
What I realized was that replacing the (Pane)-cast by an AnchorPane seemed to cause less artifacts but it doesn't remove them all.

Comment: I tried running your test case on a couple of configurations and the rendering artefacts you mentioned always reproduced on those configurations.  Configurations tested: Java 1.8u144 and Java 9.0.4 on OS X 10.12.6 using a Mid 2014 15 inch MacBook Pro.  I recommend [submitting a bug report](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Submitting+a+Bug+Report) for this.

Comment: Hm a JavaFX-bug was not really what I was hoping for, but thanks nonetheless! I will report that then I guess

Comment: Btw just a small update: The bug was reported and was/will be fixed (don't know when) but there is a workaround for it:
 java -Dprism.dirtyopts=false
In order to make your program running, just add the above java option.

Comment: If you have one, please add a link to the bug tracker issue for this so that if anybody stumbles across it here, they can check the bug fix status.

Comment: Sure:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198815

Comment: I'm having a similar issue animating white Path elements on a black background? 3.5 years later with JavaFX 15. Looks like this one's not getting solved? (OSX Monterey 12.0.1)